# Soap Header Action Not Understood

Tags: c#, web-services, soap, wsdl

I have imported a WSDL via the Service Reference dialog box in VS2010 (asmx not WCF) which contains a SendMessage method which I need to call, passing it Xml and a Command name. I'm also passing the URL of the WS. When I call this method, it causes the following exception:

SoapHeaderException: Soap Header Action Not Understood

I think I am able to read the Soap request via Fiddler, and it contains no Soap Header information. I would have expected C# to add this automatically since all the required information to create it is present.

How do I ensure the Soap Header is added??